# Shell Script - Using sed with a variable having /

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am  new to shell script and don't know much. I have a set of files on which I want to append some text. I am not sure of a better way to do it, but I am using sed to do so. I have written the following script in bash to do so(I am testing it out with one file out of the set of files in the following). Here, I am replacing  `</notepads>` with `</notepads> "\n" <text to be appended>` in order to append `<text to be appended>` after the string `</notepads>`  in the file UIL_extract.ktr. (`</notepads>` occurs only once in the file)

```
  FILE=UIL_extract.ktr
  FIND="</notepads>"
  SUB="$FIND"$'\n'`cat add.txt`
  echo "Finding $FIND in $FILE"
  echo "with $SUB"
  sed "s,${FIND},${SUB},g" $FILE > Temp.ktr
```

This is the error I get when I execute it -

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unterminated `s' command
```

Something is not right and I don't know what.

Thanks in advance.

PS - I have tried various other things. Eg. if I do -

```
sed 's,"${FIND}","${SUB}",g' $FILE > Temp.ktr
```

It probably doesn't expand the variables as it does not replace it on the output.

Comment: without testing, I think the problem is not about the slash, but the `$` in your `SUB`, the dollar between `$FIND"` and `'\n'` give it a try after removing it. it makes no sense there.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it was not needed, I removed it. I added it there as one of the resolutions about adding newline to variable question posted somewhere. I removed -
whole $'\n' from $SUB
sed still can't find $FIND though

Comment: If you're strictly appending there is a much simpler solution: `cat add.txt >> yourfile.ktr` - If you only want to append to files that have `</notepads>` in them, `for ef in $(fgrep '</notepads>') do cat add.txt >> ${ef} done` (that's not broken up correctly - comments are limited in their formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the quoting right - so that bash can read the bash variables.

```
sed 's,'"${FIND}"','"${SUB}"',g' $FILE > Temp.ktr
```

The other problem is handling the '/n' in  and possibly other characters.
I would try something like:

```
awk '{print}  /<\/notepads>/ {exit}' $FILE > /tmp/f1
awk 'BEGIN{found=0} /<\/notepads>/ {found=1;next} {if (found)print}' $FILE >/tmp/f2
cat /tmp/f1 add.txt /tmp/f2 > Temp.ktr
rm /tmp/f[23]
```

Comment: It makes sense. I have tried other similar things as well(and just tried yours too). Now I am thinking there is some nasty stuff in the file add.txt which is causing it. So I guess, I'll check that.
Thank you, I have a lead now :)

Comment: can you not have newline characters in the replacement string?

Comment: It turns out that I can't have newline in the replacement. add.txt is a file with multiple lines. I was being more stupid than what I thought.

Comment: Oh yeah, that does it. Smart.
Thank you so much. I was going to do split the file by reading them line by line. But this is way more awesome.

Comment: `'s,'${FIND}','${SUB}',g'` is much worse than the OP had, `"s,${FIND},${SUB},g"` is it leaves the shell variables unquoted and so susceptible to word splitting, globbing, etc. If you made it `'s,'"${FIND}"','"${SUB}"',g'` then you'd solve that problem, but then it's no more robust than the OP had, just more complicated. No need for temp files and multiple invocations if you're using awk, just include the contents of `add.txt` at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to SUB="$FIND"$'\n'`cat add.txt` on line #4 and it will work.

Comment: I found that the actual problem is with add.txt. It has new line characters.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the contents of file `add.txt` after you find the text `</notepads>`? That's just:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{add = add $0 ORS; next} {print} /<\/notepads>/{printf "%s",add}' add.txt UIL_extract.ktr
```

sed actually has a `r` command specifically for this, but using sed for anything multi-line is not extensible and gets very complicated very fast so you should just learn awk.

Answer (score 0):

To recap:

The *only* problem in the original code is that in an `s` function's replacement text ***literal* `\n` chars. must be `\`-escaped** - otherwise the `sed` command will *break*.

While you *could* use bash's variable expansion features to escape the newlines in `$SUB` - `SUB=${SUB//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}` - a **much simpler solution is to use `sed`'s `r <file>` function** (as @Ed Morton states in his answer), which can be used to output a file's content whenever the preceding context address (regex) matches (after outputting the current line):

```
FIND='</notepads>'
sed "\,${FIND}, r add.txt" "$FILE" > Temp.ktr
```

Note that in order to use `,` as the regex delimiter, the initial delimiter must be `\`-escaped.